# Sending multiple data types in Angular post to php

Tags: php, angularjs, post

I'm trying to work out how I can send two data types to my php file.

I have a big array which posts correctly and I can retrieve it correctly. I now want to be able to send a string with it and retrieve it separately in my php file. The reason for this is because dependent on the value of the string I will be sending a different array.

```
function send(result, selectedButton) {
  console.log(selectedButton)
  return $http.post(apiUrl + 'write_to_database.php', {'data': result}).then(function(data){
    return $q.when(data);
  });
}
```

so to retrieve the above in php I want something like this

```
$data = $_POST['data'];
$selectedButton = $_POST['selectedButton'];
```

Using the code above how can I send the selectedButton the php file so I can work out what array was sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
function send(result, selectedButton) {
    console.log(selectedButton)  
    return $http.post(apiUrl + 'write_to_database.php', {'data':result,'selectedButton': selectedButton}).then(function(data){
       return $q.when(data);
    });
}
```

Alternatively you can also pass it as query string parameter with the post url

```
return $http.post(apiUrl + 'write_to_database.php?selectedButton=' + selectedButton, {'data': result})
```

Comment: I've tried both ways and only the array comes through, not the string. Am I retrieving it correctly? $data = $_POST['data'];

Comment: Okay it works but I need to add the selectedButton to the function parameter and also within return $q.when(data, selectedButton). You may need to update the answer. Thanks

Comment: It is a hackish answer. It does not address **why** OP cannot access data by $_POST.